# MATLAB: Error using vertcat. Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have two tables containing strings that I want to concatenate. The strings will vary in length from concatenation to concatenation. I have checked that all variables match/dimensions match.

That is the baffling part: I have two tables of equal dimensions with equal variables, but I will still get the error listed in the title. In a nutshell: has this sort of error ever happened before or is there something else going on with my code (rather, is this sort of error possible)? If this has happened before, what were some fixes? Again: I have verified multiple times that the dimensions of the two tables do agree.

**Top-Level Loop that calls the concatenation functions.**

```
function saveAnnotation(obj)

    switch obj.annotationMode 
        case 1 
            isCellEmpty = isFieldEmpty(obj);

            if isCellEmpty 
                createNewAnnoTable(obj); 
            elseif ~isCellEmpty
                addToAnnoTable(obj); 
            end

            set(obj.regionSelector, 'Enable', 'off'); 

        case 2 
            isCellEmpty = isFieldEmpty(obj); 

            if isCellEmpty 
                createNewAnnoTable(obj); 
            elseif ~isCellEmpty
                addToAnnoTable(obj); 
            end 

        case 3 
            if obj.selectedLead == 1
                for i = 1:6 
                    fillRecPairInfo(obj, i); 
                    isCellEmpty = isFieldEmpty(obj, i); 
                    if isCellEmpty 
                        createNewAnnoTable(obj, i);
                    elseif ~isCellEmpty 
                        addToAnnoTable(obj, i); 
                    end

                end 
            elseif obj.selectedLead == 2
                for i = 7:12
                    fillRecPairInfo(obj, i); 
                    isCellEmpty = isFieldEmpty(obj, i); 
                    if isCellEmpty 
                        createNewAnnoTable(obj, i);
                    elseif ~isCellEmpty 
                        addToAnnoTable(obj, i);
                    end
                end
            end

        case 4
            for i = 1:12
                fillRecPairInfo(obj, i); 
                isCellEmpty = isFieldEmpty(obj, i); 
                if isCellEmpty
                    createNewAnnoTable(obj, i);
                elseif ~isCellEmpty 
                    addToAnnoTable(obj, i);
                end
            end
    end
    end
```

**The "isFieldEmpty" function**

```
function fieldEmpty = isFieldEmpty(obj, varargin)

    pairSelection = obj.selectedPair; 
    displayedPair = find(pairSelection(1:12) == 1); 


    switch obj.annotationMode
        case 1
            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6 
                    fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData);
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6
                    fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData);
                end
            end
        case 2
            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6 
                    fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData);
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6
                    fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData);
                end
            end
        case 3
            checkIndx = varargin{1};
            if checkIndx <= 6
                fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData); 
            elseif checkIndx > 6
                fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData); 
            end 

        case 4 
            checkIndx = varargin{1}; 
            if checkIndx <= 6
                fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData); 
            elseif checkIndx > 6
                fieldEmpty = isempty(obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData); 
            end 

    end
end
```

**The "createNewAnnoTable" function**

```
function createNewAnnoTable(obj, varargin)
    pairSelection = obj.selectedPair; 
    displayedPair = find(pairSelection(1:12) == 1); 

    switch obj.annotationMode
        case 1
            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6 
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow;
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow; 
                end
            end

        case 2
            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6 
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow;
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow; 
                end
            end

        case 3
            checkIndx = varargin{1};
            if checkIndx <= 6
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow;
            elseif checkIndx > 6
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow; 
            end

        case 4
            checkIndx = varargin{1};
            if checkIndx <= 6
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow;
            elseif checkIndx > 6
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData.Annotations = obj.nextRow; 
            end

    end
end
```

**The "addToAnnoTable" function**

```
function addToAnnoTable(obj, varargin)


    switch obj.annotationMode 
        case 1
            pairSelection = obj.selectedPair; 
            displayedPair = find(pairSelection(1:12) == 1); 
            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6
                    existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData.Annotations;
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6 
                    existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData.Annotations; 
                end 
            end

            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6 
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow];
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow]; 
                end
            end

        case 2
            pairSelection = obj.selectedPair; 
            displayedPair = find(pairSelection(1:12) == 1); 
            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6
                    existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData.Annotations;
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6 
                    existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData.Annotations; 
                end 
            end

            for i = 1:length(displayedPair)
                if displayedPair(i) <= 6 
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, displayedPair(i)).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow];
                elseif displayedPair(i) > 6
                    obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (displayedPair(i) - 6)).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow]; 
                end
            end

        case 3
            checkIndx = varargin{1};
            if checkIndx <= 6
                existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData.Annotations;
            elseif checkIndx > 6 
                existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData.Annotations; 
            end 

            if checkIndx <= 6 
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow];
            elseif checkIndx > 6
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow]; 
            end

        case 4
            checkIndx = varargin{1};
            if checkIndx <= 6
                existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData.Annotations;
            elseif checkIndx > 6 
                existingTable = obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData.Annotations; 
            end 

            if checkIndx <= 6 
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L1(1, checkIndx).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow];
            elseif checkIndx > 6
                obj.ephysData.sortedMontageMatrix.(obj.selectedSession).L2(1, (checkIndx - 6)).UserData.Annotations = [existingTable; obj.nextRow]; 
            end

     end     
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet related to this?

Comment: Could you show an example of the matrices you are trying to cat?

Comment: @scrappedcola Hi sorry for the late response! I was able to figure it out. If you look at the answer I posted below you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research I realized that my table didn't contain exclusively strings. ***It actually contained a combination of stand-alone strings and string-cells.*** When MATLAB would try to concatenate the stand-alone strings, that is when the error would occur.

I suppose the issue is that MATLAB handles strings like a vector of characters not a single object so putting it in a single column in a table can cause concatenation problems when the new string is a different length.

I was able to fix this problem by making every stand-alone string a string-cell. That has fixed my problem because now MATLAB is concatenating cells rather than strings.